# Jquery "get" button feature

Tags: jquery

so this one has me perplexed. I have this button that retrieves values and it works. The value in the system.out(second to last line) is always correct but I can never get it to populate the line following it. I can hard code some string in the line afterwards and it works.   What am I doing wrong?

```
 b = $( "button" ).button();    
 b.click(function() {
 var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:'/content-admin-webapp/contents/screening/findEntity?
    resdID=' + document.getElementById("resdID").value
    +','+document.getElementById("resdName").value,         
    dataType:"text",
    error: function (data, status, e){                          
       alert(e);}
      });
     success:
     <%      
 String  aResdName = "";
 RestrictedEntityListData foundAttribute = (RestrictedEntityListData) request.getAttribute("restrictedEntitys");             
    if (foundAttribute != null) {
      java.util.List<RestrictedEntityData> foundResds = 
      foundAttribute.getRestrictedEntys();                           
         for(RestrictedEntityData  eachFoundResds :  foundResds)
             { 
             if(foundResds.get(0) != null){ 
                         aResdName = 
   foundResds.get(0).getRestrictedEntityName(); 
                        }
                    }   
                 }  
               System.out.print(aResdName); 
             %>   
             $('#resdName').val(<%=aResdName%>); 
         });
```

Comment: I'm a little rusty on my JSP but IIRC you can't put JSP code inside of a javascript function, since the JSP runs when the page is loaded, so you can't call it later from JS, since its already run and done by the time you would call it (or something like that)?

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is quote around that value.

```
$('#resdName').val('<%=aResdName%>');
```

Comment: So tried that and it didnt work. I think its a timing issue now that I think about it. Instead of aResdName  being empty string I changed  to be set to "test123" and that works, I noticed it happens after my code runs and works. So I think my found value is getting splatted. Is there a way to delay the setting of the value till my code runs?